# AssignedTo Data Returning differently than other same type columns

Tags: json, power-automate

So I am running into an odd issue. One I can't quite figure out. I am building a flow to send a user(AssignedTo) an email if a task is not completed, and the due date is within 10 days of today. That logic works. The issue I am running into is why in the Get Items that the assigned to has its properties in square brackets and the other columns that are person/group do not. All properties have data, I just removed it for privacy sake

For example:

```
"AssignedTo": [{
     "@odata.type":
     "DisplayName": 
     "Email": 
     "Picture":
     "Department":
     "JobTitle":
 }],
```

Versus the Author(CreatedBy) column along with a custom person/group column I created.

```
"EmailTest": {
     "@odata.type": 
     "DisplayName": 
     "Email": 
     "Picture": 
     "Department":
     "JobTitle": 
 },
```

I am using the expression which works. But when I change Author to AssignedTo it is just blank, and I am not sure how to edit the expression to account for the square braces.

```
items('Apply_to_each_2')?['Author/Email']
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that AssignedTo will ALWAYS return as an array of objects. Even if you change the column settings to now allow multiple selections and also to only a person. I solved it by using this expression

array(items('Apply_to_each_3'))?[0]?['AssignedTo']?[0]?['Email']